# Create a column with date time adding months

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame with a column indicating the number of months. I would like to create a new column, starting from an initial date, let’s say `2015-01-01` and add all the months to this initial date. For example, if the month column has values `[0, 1, 2, …,72]`, then I would like to have a column called Date of the form `[2015-01-01,2015-02-01,2015-03-01,…]`.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: use a [DateOffset](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) of n month, with n depending on the value in your 'month' column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) and add to `datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n': [0,1,2,72]})

start = '2015-01-01'

df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(start) + df['n'].apply(lambda x: pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=x))
print (df)
    n        new
0   0 2015-01-01
1   1 2015-02-01
2   2 2015-03-01
3  72 2021-01-01
```